# Spring DeferredResult getting no response in ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, long-polling

I am trying to test DeferredResult to perform ajax long polling, but even before long polling, with simple data itslef, I am getting only an empty response in my ajax callback.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz")
@ResponseBody
@Async
public DeferredResult<String> longPoll() {

    return new DeferredResult<String>(1000L, "sample");
}
```

What am I missing? Moreover, if I give timeout as 5000L, then shouldn't the response be after 5 secs, which is also not working.
I tried using Callable also but still empty response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz")
@ResponseBody
@Async
public Callable<String> longPoll() {

    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "someView";
        }
    };
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sample.longPoll")
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@Import()
public class CustomRootConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor()).excludePathPatterns("/resources/**");
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `@Async`. Please also provide your spring configuration.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner if I remove `@Async`, it throws error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container`

Comment: Exactly! You have to enable async suoport at the servlet level. The `@Async` annotation is not meant for that, but for running a method in the background. If you're using Spring Boot, async support is already included. Otherwise, you have to explicitly enable it.